# Unable to acquire AP network IP and DNS on a ESP32 MCU

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm getting the following error on serial output (verbose mode) when my smart device , ESP32 S3 tries to connect over WIFI to the Access point (AP). The SSID is `TheScientist`

Below is the serial output:

```
Connecting to TheScientist
[  1064][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:929] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 0 - WIFI_READY
[  1098][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:338] _arduino_event_cb(): STA Started
[  1099][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:97] set_esp_interface_ip(): Configuring Station static IP: 0.0.0.0, MASK: 0.0.0.0, GW: 0.0.0.0
[  1099][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:929] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 2 - STA_START
.......[  4750][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:360] _arduino_event_cb(): STA Disconnected: SSID: TheScientist, BSSID: 3c:cd:5d:a7:f1:13, Reason: 15
[  4750][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:929] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 5 - STA_DISCONNECTED
[  4758][W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:950] _eventCallback(): Reason: 15 - 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the verbose debug serial output shows a

`Reason: 15 - 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT`

in reality the timeout is due to usage of a password longer than the 32 char allowed on ESP32 MCUs . In summary, any ESP32 MCU to successfully connect to any WIFI Access Point , the Network password must not exceed 32 char long.